# Remapping both mouse and keyboard to a gamepad

Tags: 10.10, configuration, games, gamepad

Since Halloween, I have been really enjoying [Frictional Games'](http://www.frictionalgames.com/site/games) Amnesia on Ubuntu.  My next goal is to get the other offerings they have.

Unfortunately, there is not a gamepad setting for this game (and many others out there).  I know there is software like rejoystick that allows the mapping of keyboard keys to a gamepad.  However, since this game incorporates the mouse, is there a solution to map both over?

Thanks in advance.

Update:  I have found on [playdeb.net](http://playdeb.net) QJoypad.  It allows the mapping of both keyboard and mouse.  Unfortunately, I still seem to have trouble with the mouse when entering Amnesia.

Comment: I was googling the same problem today (wanted to play minecraft with a gamepad ;). I found joy2key, but have the same problem with mouse/mousebutton emulation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is QJoyPad. As I stated in my update on the question, it does allow the mapping of both keyboard and mouse.

Amnesia is a little bit of an oddball in the configuration because the game uses, according to their [forum](http://www.frictionalgames.com/forum/thread-4569.html), relative mouse movements.  The solution is launch the game via a terminal after typing in `export SDL_VIDEO_X11_DGAMOUSE=0`. After doing so, my test with the mouse worked fine.

By the way, the controller I am using with QJoyPad is a Logitech Dual Action.

Answer (score 7):

Following [**Grumbel**'s answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/116480/32413), I tried **xboxdrv** solution with the support of his [link](http://pingus.seul.org/~grumbel/xboxdrv/) and specially [this page](http://pingus.seul.org/~grumbel/xboxdrv/xboxdrv.html):

### 1.  Install **xboxdrv 0.8.2** from Ubuntu Software Center.

Install also **uinput** and **joydev** if needed. 
I did it this way `sudo modprobe uinput` + `sudo modprobe joydev`

### 2. Need to know the **event** of the gamepad:

Launch `udevadm monitor --udev` and then plug the game pad :

```
$ udevadm monitor --udev
monitor will print the received events for:
UDEV - the event which udev sends out after rule processing

UDEV  [6722.377700] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.3/usb5/5-1 (usb)
UDEV  [6722.383264] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.3/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [6722.383333] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.3/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/0003:046D:C218.0003 (hid)
UDEV  [6722.383389] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.3/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/0003:046D:C218.0003/hidraw/hidraw1 (hidraw)
UDEV  [6722.387123] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.3/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/input/input10 (input)
UDEV  [6722.399284] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.3/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/input/input10/event8 (input)
UDEV  [6722.412128] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.3/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/input/input10/js0 (input)
```

I conclude that my gamepad's event is **/dev/input/event8**

### 3. Display names of every keys, axis, buttons of the gamepad.

The idea is to launch `xboxdrv` and test every buttons and note the result on paper.

```
$ sudo xboxdrv --evdev /dev/input/event8 --evdev-debug
Your Xbox/Xbox360 controller should now be available as:
/dev/input/js1
/dev/input/event9
Press Ctrl-c to quit, use '--silent' to suppress the event output
EV_ABS ABS_X 128
EV_ABS ABS_Y 128
...
```

In my case the result is:
[image]

### 4. Set the config file

Create a **xboxdrv-mouse.ini** file to set X Y axis and left and right mouse button.
Here I set gamepad buttons <kbd>2</kbd> for left mouse button and <kbd>3</kbd> for right mouse button:

```
[xboxdrv]
evdev=/dev/input/event8
silent=true

[evdev-absmap]
ABS_X=x1
ABS_Y=y1

[ui-axismap]
x1=REL_X:10
y1=REL_Y:-10

[evdev-keymap]
BTN_THUMB=a
BTN_THUMB2=b

[ui-buttonmap]
a=BTN_LEFT
b=BTN_RIGHT

# EOF #
```

Note that value for REl_X and REL_Y seems to define the speed of the mouse, and by defining a negative value it invert the axis (see here for REL_Y)

An other example with more button definition

```
[xboxdrv]
evdev=/dev/input/event8
silent=true

[evdev-absmap]
ABS_X=x1
ABS_Y=y1
ABS_HAT0X=x2
ABS_HAT0Y=y2

[ui-axismap]
x1=REL_X:10
y1=REL_Y:-10
x2=KEY_LEFT:KEY_RIGHT
y2=KEY_DOWN:KEY_UP

[evdev-keymap]
BTN_TRIGGER=x
BTN_TOP=y
BTN_THUMB=a
BTN_THUMB2=b
BTN_PINKIE=rt
BTN_BASE2=rb
BTN_TOP2=lt
BTN_BASE=lb
BTN_BASE3=back
BTN_BASE4=start

[ui-buttonmap]
x=KEY_KPENTER
y=KEY_SPACE
a=BTN_LEFT
b=BTN_RIGHT
rt=KEY_KP8
rb=KEY_KP2
lt=KEY_KP6
lb=KEY_KP4
back=KEY_LEFTSHIFT
start=KEY_RIGHTCTRL

# EOF #
```

### 5. Launch it

```
sudo xboxdrv --config xboxdrv-mouse.ini
```

To avoid launching it with `sudo`, [create a udev rule](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/gizmod/index.php?title=HOWTO_-_Setting_Input_Device_Permissions_-_Creating_a_udev_Rule).

### CONCLUSION

It works fine, it's the best solution for me.

Answer (score 1):

To map a gamepad to mouse, try [js2mouse](http://cedric.vincent.perso.free.fr/Projets/index.html).

In Ubuntu 11.10, qjoypad doesn't seem to work properly, because a left-click on its icon in the notification area triggers a right-click menu with no way to access setup. You can, however, use Rejoystick (also available in PlayDeb). The first time you run it (running `rejoystick`) you assign keys to your gamepad's buttons, then save. Next you run `rejoystick -d` and you won't get a GUI, rejoystick is running in the background and will use your gamepad's buttons for the assigned keys.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely recommend [AntiMicro](http://www.ryochan7.com/projects/antimicro/), which picks up from where the discontinued QJoyPad left off. I'm using it right now to play Civ V from my couch and am loving every minute of it. It was easy to setup and use (and yes, it lets you map both keyboard as well as mouse --- including left/right wheel scrolling).