# ubuntu 13.04 terminal won't read my .ini file

Tags: 13.04, command-line

I get this every time I attempt to access it

```
CommandLineParser::read_config_file(): couldn't open xboxdrv-mouse.ini
```

the command I was using was `sudo xboxdrv --config xboxdrv-mouse.ini`
it was for this tutorial on calibrating my logitech f310 to control my mouse cursor.
[Remapping both mouse and keyboard to a gamepad](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14457/remapping-both-mouse-and-keyboard-to-a-gamepad/207532#207532?newreg=cf7c7745386046ea9260e7634c87a004) ( the second comment ).

Answer (score 1):

The most likely solution is it can't find the file because you're not specifying the full path. Find out what the full path is and use that. Eg:

```
sudo xboxdrv --config /home/oli/xboxdrv-mouse.ini
```

You can check the path by running `stat /home/oli/xboxdrv-mouse.ini`. If that tells you it's anything but a file, you're probably using the wrong path.