# How to set up a gamepad?

Tags: gamepad

I have an old gamepad which I managed to pair thorough bluetooth. Ubuntu reacts automatically to volume down and up. But the other keys dont show any action.

Can you tell me how this mapping works and how I can customize it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remapping both mouse and keyboard to a gamepad](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14457/remapping-both-mouse-and-keyboard-to-a-gamepad)

Comment: Could you edit your question to include more information about the specific gamepad you're trying to connect? There are a lot of old, weird gamepads out there.